# Where to define routes when working with laravel and angular JS project

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on project using laravel and angular JS. And I am a little bit confused, about where to use routes in angular so I can make a spa, or I should specify the folders and pages using route.php of laravel framework too.
Or should I configure them both ?

Please any help and sorry if I didn't post a code.

Comment: you can place the routes in the `routes.php` itself or if you want to mange your code in different files you can create a `api_route.php` or any other relevant php file and include it to your `routeServiceProvider`'s `map` method

Comment: But I need to make a single page app so should I add and repeat the same route but in the angular JS `app.js` file too ?

Comment: make a single route which bootstraps the angular app after that the angular has it's own routes/templates, it communicates with your backend through exposed API's

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180772/laravel-changing-from-blade-to-js-frontend-framework/39181345#39181345

Comment: yes, you would need to define the routes in angular's `app.js` for SPA to consume your Laravel's apis. and Laravel routes are to define those apis.